# MySQL 5.6 : Access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost' when password contains backslash

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

**EDIT** : I figured the issue: my password contained the character `\`. Typing the password without this character worked. This is apparently [due to a character encoding problem](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36010).

---

I recently installed MySQL Server 5.6 on my machine, running ubuntu 14.04.

I have followed the [manual to install mysql from the APT repository](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/). During the installation, I was asked a password for the root user. I set one.

Now, following [some post-installation tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/default-privileges.html) for example, trying to run SQL queries, I could not get access to mysql shell.

I tried running the command:

> mysql -u root -p

then typing my password, and got the message:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have tried to run this command with other parameters, without `-p`, `-h localhost`, `-h 127.0.0.1`, with similar results.

I have tried some suggestions found here and there, like [a manual to reset permission with an init file when starting the service `sudo service start --init-file=/path/to/file`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html), or some suggestions to start the service with the option `--skip-grant-tables`. These commands started the service successfully but I still could not log in.

After starting the service, I see the following error.log

```
InnoDB: 5.6.22 started;
Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
'127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
/usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

I ran out of options to try to get access to my installation of MySQL. Given that few people seem to get that problem after a fresh install, I suppose I missed something important but I cannot figure what.

If you have any hint to figure why I cannot log in, let me know.

Comment: If you provide the password in the shell command, any difference? Run the command `mysql -u root -pPASSWORDHERE`

Comment: @SetSailMedia I got no difference, I got the same results (and a warning this may be insecure to do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the issue: my password contained the character `\`. Typing the password without this character worked. This is apparently [due to a character encoding problem](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36010). – Vince